# How do I access my home folder in a separate partition that has been mounted on a new version of Ubuntu

Tags: mount, permissions, directory

I ran into problems when I was using Ubuntu 14.04 my log in screen was looping and I checked on-line and saw a solution that told me to try

```
chown -R $USER:$USER sudo
```

so apparently I recurrently changed root access so my `/usr/bin` is now owned by `mickey:mickey` instead of `root:root`, well I know that now. I installed a new Ubuntu OS alongside the old one and now I'm trying to access the home folder of the old OS, which is a separate partition but I can't. I need access to it so I can save other important documents in folders like

- Documents
- Downloads
- Video etc.

this is the home folder in the partition for the old OS

[image]

Denying me access into the mickey folder

[image]

Comment: Try to change the folders owner from the mounted drive `sudo chown -R mickey:mickey /home` Make sure to run it from the folder in the screen shot.

Comment: this is something like what i did that made me loose superuser privilege wouldn't this do the same ?

Comment: It will make your new user the owner of that folder, so yes it is close to what you ran when you broke it because it is the same procedure but this time it will take ownership of the old home folder, it will give you privileges on that folder, not take them away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to use absolute paths so you don't change again things you need to stay how they are. So the below commands will make your old `home` directory readable for you.

```
# this makes only the home directory in the old drive owned by you
sudo chown -R mickey:mickey /media/f806aa57-553c-43bc-8338-37851dc128ad/home
```

So now that you have done this I assume you want to copy the content of your old user directory over to your new user directory, so lets make a folder for that first so we don't mess up settings now present in the main home directory.

```
# creating a directory for backing up your home folder in
mkdir ~/backup-old-home
```

Now copying the contents over to the backup directory

```
cp /media/f806aa57-553c-43bc-8338-37851dc128ad/home/mickey/* ~/backup-old-home
```

Now it is time for you to check if all got copied to your new user directories sub-folder. In case something went wrong the files are still present where they are now.

Comment: I tried this and now it says "me" owns the home folder shouldn't it be owned by "root" ?, also i still can't see folder like my Documents, Videos, and Downloads are they gone forever or are they hidden ?, if they're hidden how can i find them ?

Comment: The whole content of your old home folder should now be in `~/backup-old-home` so do a `cd ~/backup-old-home && ls -a`

Comment: & Markkirby Thank you guys! i can see all my files now, i would copy them into an external hard drive because my old partition is larger than the new one. is there a way i can do that from the cmd line ?

Comment: If you're not that firm with command line commands i would do it over GUI, but have a look at the `cp` command or the `mv` command.

Comment: If my answer helped you you can accept it by clicking the check-mark beside it.